# Jquery mask with JQuery 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use a very simple mask for input with JQuery :

http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999?9-9999");
```

But it's work with Jquery 1.7.2, but not with JQuery 1.10.1 (You can change version with left sidebar)

Someone have a idea to solve that ?

Thanks !

**Bouffe**

Comment: Migrate the plugin, $.browser has been removed from jquery as for version 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing an outdated or incorrect version of the jQuery masked input plugin. Please obtain the correct version from the official site. Reference the link below

[Digitalbush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/)

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```